# Combine values from one field in multi-columned Oracle 11g table

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

Combine values from one field in multi-columned table.

T1 has duplicated values in several columns, then non-unique values in the final column.  The need is to return the unique values from the first 6 columns, then combine the  non-unique  values in the final column.  Col1 is the focal point, so the accumulation comes from the assorted values in col7 . The columns in between do not really matter, they could be unique or non-unique.  They do need to show up in the returned values.

The sample is highly simplified to the real problem, but the matter at hand is  to return col1, everything in between, then concatenate the values accumulated from col7

```
  CREATE TABLE T1
  (
    COL1  NUMBER,
    COL2  NUMBER,
    COL3  NUMBER,
    COL4  NUMBER,
    COL5  NUMBER,
    COL6  NUMBER,
    COL7  NUMBER);--


INSERT INTO  T1 VALUES( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
INSERT INTO  T1 VALUES( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 97);
INSERT INTO  T1 VALUES( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 147);

Desired results
    COL1, COL2,    COL3,     COL4,       COL5,     COL6,       COL7
      1    2         3         1           2         3        7, 97,147
```

I am thinking it would require two self joins with concatenation, but don't know how to create the scripting.

Any and all suggestions and insights appreciated.

Comment: LISTAGG function could help you.

Comment: thank you for your reply.                                                                                               SELECT col1,        LISTAGG(col7, ',')             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) AS names
      FROM (
           SELECT UNIQUE
              col7,
              col1
                      FROM t1
       )
 GROUP BY col1

Comment: I can't get the display to format the code, but it does work and give me almost everything I need.  What I still cannot get to work is adding the columns I between 1 and 7.  listagg gives me the desired results for col 1 and col7, but anywhere I try to add the other columns, I get an error..

Comment: i get invalid identifier no matter where i place the other columns in the scripting..  maybe make the whole thing we have so far another subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `col1` is not a primary key if it has duplicate values in the table.  You need to review your use of terminology.

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,
       listagg(col7, ',') within group (order by col7) as col7s
from t1
group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6;
```

Comment: Thank you !! My apologies.. I added the non-unique value after everything else was done and did not go back and alter text.  Your answer is exact and gives me exactly what I am looking for..  Thank you!!